# Organizing downloads in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using Google Chrome, is there a way (extension or whatever) to set a separate download folder according to file type? i.e. exe files into one folder, image files into a different one, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Belvedere](http://lifehacker.com/341950/belvedere-automates-your-self+cleaning-pc) for my chrome downloads folder, for my desktop and for other folders as well. It works fairly well.

Comment: This is such a great program. Congrats to the developer Adam Pash

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. It packs many more features in but also should do what you were requesting.

> http://damdownloader.com/