# Changing the display/sort order of downloads in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, download, file-management

Unlike a previous [question](https://superuser.com/questions/212994/organizing-downloads-in-google-chrome), I am wondering if there is a way to sort by time left or file size or any other attribute on the All Downloads (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd>) page in Chrome.

If there is, how is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this. The downloads are sorted by the order they were downloaded in. Chrome has a helpful icon that fills up as your downloads complete, providing a way to see how close to completion any download is. Also, download times depend on the download speed, which may change throughout the download. It may not be a good idea to keep changing the list of downloads based on the time left (or the download speed essentially).

Comment: Thanks, Jay - I was hoping that *wasn't* the case. <Sigh/>. (Side note - what would prevent the list from reordering if it were to be sorted on time left, for example?)

Comment: Well, if I was designing the sorting function I would make the sorting insensitive to minute changes. So only sort if speed changes by +/- 500 KB/s, which will prevent the list from being sorted continuously and still give a pretty good estimate.

Answer (score 1):

> Is [there] a way to sort by time left or file size or any other attribute on the All Downloads page in Chrome?

Not a built-in way, but there are extensions that give you better control over the history and downloads, including the ability to re-order the items:

- [History 2](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cahejgbbfgmlmjgdjlibphdjeldhagkp)
- [Recent History](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fbmkfdfomhhlonpbnpiibloacemdhjjm)
- [Chrome History X](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pdhmfkafbeailpjnpkmincfnaaimiiph)

(Some of these extensions have been available since the extension gallery first opened.)